# Delay between form initialize and show to user

Tags: c#, winapp

I want to move mouse and click on control in run time. But between form initialize and show form to user was delay about 1 second and this cause mouse clicked on the parent form of this form.
I use `Show` method, `Load` method but not fix my problem. i don't use timer.
How can i fix this? thanks.

my code to click on control is here:

```
private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, uint dwExtraInf);
int x = Convert.ToInt16(trvPointTitls.Location.X+trvPointTitls.Width-10);
int y = Convert.ToInt16(trvPointTitls.Location.Y-10);
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: It is **very** unclear why you need to use this hack to click a control.  Use trvPointTitls.PerformClick() instead.  Or just move the code in the Click event handler into a helper method and call that method directly.  Otherwise, your cursor position is wrong, it must be specified in screen coordinates.  Use the control's PointToScreen() method. -10 is wrong as well.

Comment: because of this [^](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277012/merging-two-rtf-fields-showed-in-bad-style), i force to use this solution and this solution are fix my problem